# USB driver is reading different max packet size for bulk endpoints during system init and after system init in windows ce 6 on x86 platform

Tags: windows, embedded, usb, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I am working on USB driver for **Windows CE 6 on x86 platform.**

I am facing an issue in USB driver initialization if the USB is plugged in during system init.

Normally I plugin the USB after the system is up and the USB driver reads bulk endpoints max packet size as 512 bytes and the driver gets initialized successfully.
Debug output: (in successful initialization case)

> ```
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x81, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A9000
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x82, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A98C0
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x83, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A1480
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x84, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Interrupt
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A1F60
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x1, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A5680
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x2, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A5D20
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x3, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A6500
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x4, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A74E0
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x5, MaxPkt: 512, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D19A7940
> ```

But the **problem is when the USB is plugged in during system initialization** , the USB driver reading bulk endpoints max packet size as 64 bytes(also there are some no memory available prints) and it is failing in initialization.
Debug output: (failed initialization case)

> ```
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x81, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051A200
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x82, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051AB00
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x83, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D05120E0
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x84, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Interrupt
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051B3C0
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x1, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051BD80
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x2, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051C1C0
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x3, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051C600
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x4, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051CA40
> +USBD:OpenPipe, EP: 0x5, MaxPkt: 64, Type: Bulk
> -USBD:OpenPipe success, hPipe = D051CE80
>
>
> CPhysMem AllocateMemory : No memory available
> CPipe(Bulk)::IssueTransfer - no memory for TD buffer
> ```

And I see all USB transfers are failing.

> CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::CheckForDoneTransfers - failure on TD
>   0xd06759a0, address = 1,       endpoint = 2, errorCounter = 0, status
>   field = 0x22    CQueuedPipe(Control)::CheckForDoneTransfers - failure
>   on TD 0xd067f600, address = 1, endpoint = 0, errorCounter = 0, status
>   field = 0

Can any one help me  on this issue, why it is reading different length for bulk endpoints during system init?

Comment: If the controller is being operated in USB FS (12 MB/s) mode the maximum packet length for a bulk endpoint *should be* 64 bytes.  That suggests two possibilities: during boot it's being initialized as USB FS not USB HS (on x86 these are sometimes different drivers!), or that the 512 is actually a spec violation which is being constrained in one case but not in the other.  I've seen that with a non-compliant CDCACM hack firmware with illegal 512 byte packets that would work on some operating systems but not others.

Comment: hi chris stratton,

thanks for the comment, actually In win ce 7 on x86 platform, the usb driver is reading bulk enpoints length as 512 bytes during /after system init. I am seeing this problem only on wince 6 usb driver.  I have few questions...
Is it possible to change the os design to configure the controller to operate in USB-HS mode always....?
Is there any other way to solve this issue .?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to avoid depending on the packet size.  If that's not possible, it sounds like you are into the internals of wince.